# FontAwesome icons not appearing when deploying website to Github

Tags: html, css, github, font-awesome

I'm currently using GitHub to host a website. I'm using Font Awesome to get some icons. During testing, everything worked perfectly, but when deploying to Github, the icons disappear.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Comment: can you verify that the fontawesome css is getting loaded?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: look at the web inspector that comes with your browser and look at the network/css tab. then reload the page and check to see that the fontawesome css file is loading.

Comment: Access to CSS stylesheet at 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css' from origin 'https://rido.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. This error message is showing

Comment: that is your issue and there are many posts about CORS issues on this site

Comment: I don't know how to fix that issue. Could you please provide me with some helpful links?

Comment: search this website for the error you're getting